# Fetching text from image

Tags: image, text, fetch

Is there any way to fetch the text from image files?

Let me say, I have a photocopy of a page which is having some line of code. I need to fetch that text. Is it possible to have the text. If yes what are the best way to do that?

Comment: Try Googling `"OCR"` and `"Tesseract"`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I am eager to learn how exactly the OCR works?

Comment: You can start digging at http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/df2/group__text__recognize.html.

Comment: @Bill Bell, Thanks